Disable click highlight command + output
I just updated iterm and I noticed that when I click on the window, an outline appears on the clicked command and output:
I didn't change anything, so I'm guessin is update related, but I can't find any option to disable that outline.
I'm on Build 3.5.1
How do I disable that?


Uncheck Settings > General > Selection > Clicking on a command selects it to restrict Find and Filter.
